# Help explaining a performance benchmark for VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi

The  page below lists the results of   benchmarking

http://www.vmware.com/products/vmmark/results.html

The page here

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmmark/VMmark-Dell-2009-04-21-R710.pdf  has the titles "actual" and "ratio"

What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio is actually the [consolidation ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidation_ratio), and the *actual* score is the throughput of operations for the tiles.  There are a few good links for a full explanation of the VMmark process, but its not for the faint of heart:

- http://www.vmware.com/products/vmmark/faq.html
- http://www.anandtech.com/show/2763 (recommended)

Since it sounds like you're trying to gauge the performance of your own or future server, I highly recommend the second link.  The VMMark FAQ also has a ton of info on how to interpret scores.

Best of luck!